# Fixed HoverTool TOOLTIPS when taping an element of a Bokeh plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Similar to the hovertool, I would like that when I **tap** on an element of the plot (in this case a circle), there is a window that pop up with information regarding the element (see picture below). And if I move the mouse after clicking on the element the window stays displaying. Is there is there a tooltip for taptool? I tried very hard to do so by using CustomJS but there is no way to display html content. Does anyone know how to proceed?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
imgs=[
    'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
    'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
    'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
    'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
    'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
],
fonts=[
    '<i>italics</i>',
    '<pre>pre</pre>',
    '<b>bold</b>',
    '<small>small</small>',
    '<del>del</del>'
]
))

TOOLTIPS = """
<div>
    <div>
        <img
            src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
            style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
            border="2"
        ></img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
        <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
    </div>
</div>
"""

 p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
       title="Mouse over the dots")

 p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

 show(p)
```

The code taken from https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html displays 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `TapTool` callback like in the code below. Clicking a circle displays the tooltip. Clicking elsewhere on the plot or clicking the `ResetTool` hides the tooltip. The `TapTool` callback uses the same `HoverTool` tooltip  as in your example and you can further customise it as you wish.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244088/bokeh-hovertools-which-run-arbitrary-python-code/55246644#55246644) which uses mini-plot as a tooltip.

This code is for **Bokeh v1.0.4**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS, HoverTool, Div, Row

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
x = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
y = [2, 5, 8, 3, 6],
desc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
imgs = ['https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
        'https://dods.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'],
fonts = ['<i>italics</i>',
         '<pre>pre</pre>',
         '<b>bold</b>',
         '<small>small</small>',
         '<del>del</del>' ]))
TOOLTIPS = """
<div>
    <div>
        <img
            src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
            style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
            border="2"/>
    </div>
    <div width=60px>
        <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
        <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
    </div>
</div> """

p = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400, x_range = (0, 6), y_range = (1, 9),
      title = "Mouse over the dots", tools = 'pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset,tap')
circles = p.circle('x', 'y', size = 20, source = source)
div = Div(text = '<div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute; display: none"></div>', name = 'tooltip')

code = '''  if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
                var selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
                var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

                tooltip.style.display = 'block';
                tooltip.style.left = Number(cb_data.geometries.sx) + Number(20) + 'px';
                tooltip.style.top = Number(cb_data.geometries.sy) - Number(20) + 'px';

                tp = tp.replace('@imgs', cb_data.source.data.imgs[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('@desc', cb_data.source.data.desc[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('@fonts{safe}', cb_data.source.data.fonts[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('$index', selected_index);
                tp = tp.replace('$x', Math.round(cb_data.geometries.x));
                tp = tp.replace('$y', Math.round(cb_data.geometries.y));
                tooltip.innerHTML = tp;
          } '''
p.select(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args = {'circles': circles, 'plot': p, 'tp': TOOLTIPS}, code = code)
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(code = 'if (cb_obj.indices.length == 0) document.getElementById("tooltip").style.display = \"none\"'))
layout = Row(p, div)
show(layout)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just found this and I think it has what I'm looking for, but I have a question: where does the "document" in the line `var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");` come from?

Comment: This is due to Bokeh CSS => the Bokeh tooltip is located on the page in a DOM element with id = "tooltip".

Comment: What's a DOM element?