# Bokeh TapTool running custom JS and tooltips

Tags: python, bokeh

I have an application in Bokeh showing a map with different sets of circles. I want to be able to use the TapTool to show a small display when a circle is tapped, similar to the one shown with HoverTool, running JS code and using a custom HTML template. I found a solution in the answer to [Fixed HoverTool TOOLTIPS when taping an element of a Bokeh plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481438/fixed-hovertool-tooltips-when-taping-an-element-of-a-bokeh-plot/60878072#60878072), whose output is below [image]

However, its behavior is not as expected. Instead of having the information displayed next to the selected circle with the TapTool, like HoverTool does, the information is displayed to the right of the plot, as it can be seen here  [image: screenshot of code solution output].

I know there is a very good explanation for this, like the Bokeh version in use (I tried 1.0.4, 1.4.0 and 2.0.0, with the same output) or some other configuration issue, but I cannot find it. I have also tried different browsers, just in case, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that that `Div` ends up being wrapped in another `div` that's shifted to the right because it belongs to the same `Row` as the main plot.

Here's an updated segment of the code that works with Bokeh 2.0.0:

```py
div = Div(text='<div id="tooltip"></div>')

code = '''  if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
                const selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
                const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

                const tooltip_wrapper = tooltip.parentElement.parentElement;
                if (tooltip_wrapper.className !== 'bk')
                    throw new Error('Unable to find the correct tooltip wrapper element');
                tooltip_wrapper.style.left = Number(cb_data.geometries.sx) + Number(20) + 'px';
                tooltip_wrapper.style.top = Number(cb_data.geometries.sy) - Number(20) + 'px';

                tooltip.style.display = 'block';
                tp = tp.replace('@imgs', cb_data.source.data.imgs[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('@desc', cb_data.source.data.desc[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('@fonts{safe}', cb_data.source.data.fonts[selected_index]);
                tp = tp.replace('$index', selected_index);
                tp = tp.replace('$x', Math.round(cb_data.geometries.x));
                tp = tp.replace('$y', Math.round(cb_data.geometries.y));
                tooltip.innerHTML = tp;
          } '''
p.select(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args={'circles': circles, 'tp': TOOLTIPS}, code=code)
```